# How to pin Steam games to Windows 7 task bar

Tags: steam, windows-7

When I right-click on a game on my Steam Library, I have the option to add a shortcut to my desktop.

[image]

However, I can NOT put that shortcut in my Windows 7 task bar with other programs and games.

Can someone explain **how to pin Steam games to Windows 7 task bar ?**

Also, it might be useful for others to explain the solution for Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be to run the game, then right click on its icon in the taskbar and pick "Pin this program to taskbar".

If the game is full-screen by default, you should be able to minimise it by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> until you reach your desktop.

[image: Pinning a steam game to task bar]

I believe every version of Windows that allows taskbar pinning should work using this method.